# How to populate the JTextArea from method with System.out.println()?

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I have a problem with JTextArea... I have a method that connect to Database via DB manager and get Hash Table with Result set. After that I printed the values in console. Now I must to change console to JTextArea. This is a method from my class:

```
public void viewSystemProperties(){

    PropertiesDTO pdto = new PropertiesDTO();
    PropertiesManager pMng = new PropertiesDBmanager();

    pdto.setPropDTO(pMng.getProperties().getPropDTO());
    Iterator<String> it = pdto.getPropDTO().keySet().iterator();

    String key = null, value = null;

    System.out.println("\t\t**************************");
    System.out.println("\t\t*    PROPERTY TABLE:     *");
    System.out.println("\t\t**************************\n");

    while (it.hasNext()){

        key = (String)it.next();
        value = pdto.getPropDTO().get(key);
        System.out.println("  " + key + "\t-------------------\t
                                        ["+value+"]\n");      

    }// while

}// viewSystemProperties()
```

Instead of **System.out.println** it must be printed in JTextArea... Thanks for help.

Comment: Use `StringBuilder` to form the whole output and set it to textarea using `setText` method.

Comment: `PROPERTY TABLE:`  This data seems like it would be better presented in a `JTable`.  (And please don't SHOUT at the user, Swing has more subtle ways to draw attention to elements of a GUI.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just create a JTextArea object and use `setText(String t)` method instead of `System.out.println()`.

```
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
textArea.setText("Mystring");
```

Here your Mystring can be `StringBuilder` object's string representation using `toString()`.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while (it.hasNext()){

key = (String)it.next();
value = pdto.getPropDTO().get(key);

sb.append("  " + key + "\t-------------------\t
                                    ["+value+"]\n"); 
}
```

Now using `setText()` method.

```
textArea.setText(sb.toString());
```

[JTextArea tutorial Java Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html)

Comment: JTextArea locates in another GUI class that calls the method... How I can transfer the data from this method to text area?

Comment: in your `viewSystemProperties()` method you are returning void instead of that return a `string`. And than create an object of the class containing `viewSystemProperties()` method in your GUI class and access the method. example:  textArea.setText(myobj.viewSystemProperties());

Answer (score 2):

Use StringBuffer for building the content for your JTextArea. After that use JTextArea.setText() method to set the content.

```
public String viewSystemProperties(){

PropertiesDTO pdto = new PropertiesDTO();
PropertiesManager pMng = new PropertiesDBmanager();

pdto.setPropDTO(pMng.getProperties().getPropDTO());
Iterator<String> it = pdto.getPropDTO().keySet().iterator();

String key = null, value = null;
StringBuffer text = new StringBuffer();
text.append("\t\t**************************");
text.append("\t\t*    PROPERTY TABLE:     *");
text.append("\t\t**************************\n");

while (it.hasNext()){

    key = (String)it.next();
    value = pdto.getPropDTO().get(key);

text.append("  " + key + "\t-------------------\t
                                        ["+value+"]\n"); 

}// while
return text.toString
```

}// viewSystemProperties()**

```
textArea.setText(yourClass.viewSystemProperties());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `StringBuffer` Class. make one `StringBuffer` Variable and keep on appending each `System.out.println()` you have done. at the end use `setText()` method to set the `StringBuffer's` `toString()` value.

Comment: StringBuilder is more efficient than StringBuffer, mainly because it's not thread-safe. When working in a single thread (like here), you want StringBuilder.

Comment: yes, I agree that is why I also gave +1 to Ahmed's Comment. But as I can not repeat his answer, I gave another answer as second view.